# InfluxDB node module not inserting data

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, influxdb

I just started experimenting with influxDB and influxDB node module.

I have the following code, that inserts some random data every second.
I get no errors but yet no data is added to my time series.

The code is:

```js
var influxdb = require('influxdb');
var sleep = require('sleep');
var connection = influxdb('172.21.5.67', 8086);
connection.auth({ name: 'root', password: 'root' });

var db;
var ISCSIDataSeries;

function random (low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
}

function doInsert(i) {
    if (db == undefined) {
        db = connection.database('test');
        console.log('established the db connection');
    }

    if (ISCSIDataSeries == undefined) {
        ISCSIDataSeries = db.series('SCSIData');
        console.log('the series SCSIData is established');
    }

    var reads = random(1000, 10000);
    var writes = random(2000, 20000);
    var IOS = random(100000, 1000000);

    ISCSIDataSeries.writePoints({
        'columns': ['Volume', 'Reads', 'Writes'],
        'points':  [reads, writes, IOS]
    });

    db.save();
}

var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    sleep.sleep(1);
    doInsert(i);
    i ++;
}

console.log('so long folks');
```

At the end of the run I see no data entered.
Any experience with this package?

Comment: There is a good article https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-with-node-influx/ how to start with InfluxDB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers of InfluxDB. We don't use node so I wasn't familiar with the library, but I tried your snippet and indeed it doesn't work. It turns out that the `influxdb` library isn't up to date and was last updated four months ago, during which InfluxDB api went through significant changes. I recommend you switch to [the influx package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/influx) instead which seems to be more actively maintained. I modified your code snippet to work with the other package and it works succesfuly:

```
var influxdb = require('influx');
var sleep = require('sleep');

var root = new influxdb.InfluxDB('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root');
root.createDatabase('SCSIData', function(err) {
  if (err && err.message.indexOf("exist") == -1) {
    console.log("Cannot create db", err);
    process.exit(1);
  };

  var client = new influxdb.InfluxDB('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'SCSIData');

  function random (low, high) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low); }

  function doInsert(i) {
    var reads = random(1000, 10000);
    var writes = random(2000, 20000);
    var IOS = random(100000, 1000000);


    client.writePoint("series.name", {
      'Volume': IOS,
      'Reads': reads,
      'Writes': writes
    }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Cannot write data", err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    });
  }

  var i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    doInsert(i);
    i++;
  }

  client.query("select count(Reads) from series.name", function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Cannot write data", err);
    }

    console.log("result", result)
    console.log("Number of points: ", result[0].points[0][1]);
  })

});

console.log('so long folks');
```

Comment: Thank you so very. This does work and I will switch to this package.

Comment: I have used this code . But it can not connect to influxdb?